# Serialize dynamic method and call after deserialization

Tags: c#-4.0, serialization, dynamic, deserialization

It there a way to serialize a method added to a dynamic type, deserialize it, then call the deserialized method? Here is an example:

```
dynamic d = new ExpandoObject();

d.Property = "Test";
d.Method = new Action<string>(Console.WriteLine);
d.Method(d.Property); //Writes "Test"

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d);

var d2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(json, new ExpandoObjectConverter());
Console.WriteLine(d2.Property); //Writes "Test"
d2.Method(d2.Property); //throws an exception

Console.ReadLine();
```

The exception thrown is:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in
>   System.Core.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot invoke a non-delegate type

Comment: Of course there's always some way to serialize things such that "deserialization" has the same results.  Out-of-the-box?  No, you'll have to write something to re-create the Action<string> delegate because it points to a method, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You're using JSON as your serialization format, that will throw away any methods, because JSON only cares about objects.

See the definition in  http://json.org/   JSON knows only about object {} , array[] and value (*key*: *val*).

If you want your C# object to be somehow *intact* as it was in memory before serialization, I would use the binary formatter instead.